# Is it possible to sent Cucumber (JS) test result to Kiwi TCMS and change status of test cases

Tags: automation, cucumber, kiwi-tcms

I have got Cucumber + nodejs test automation. Automation testing results are saved as junit-report.xml and testNg Report. We use Kiwi TCMS for test cases. I want to add testcase, testrun id to Cucumber side and change status of related test id if automated test cases failed in cucumber.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about "[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and "[how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)". This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

please provide more information b/c between the language barrier and vague descriptions I'm not really sure what your problem is. Here are some facts:

- There is no Cucumber plugin/parser for Kiwi TCMS b/c nobody has asked for this until now. Please open an issue on GitHub so we can track this request and work on it.
- There is a junit.xml parser, see https://github.com/kiwitcms/junit.xml-plugin for examples how to use it.

Provide an example output from Cucumber and also your junit-report.xml file so we can see better what is going on. The current parser matches the test cases by name so if something fails in your automated test suite it will be reported as failed in Kiwi TCMS too.

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want. Maybe provide some more examples of how you think it should look like so we can figure it out.

Comment: I see, I add feature and xml file of test below

Answer (score 0):

Example of cucumber login scenario and result of executed test as junit. These two test cases available in Kiwi. I want to sent status of executed test cases to kiwi . 
@login
Feature: Authentication Management

```
Scenario: Login with invalid username and password
    Given I am on the Portia home page
    When I login with "Resman Priority" account username "invalidUsername" password "invalidPassword"
    Then I should see a bad login error "Error:"

Scenario: Login with Resman Priority account and check Admin Preferences Menu
    Given I am on the Portia home page
    When I login with "Resman Priority" account username "usernameResman" password "passwordResman"
    Then I should login
    And I should see my username
    And I should not see Admin Preference menu
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="authentication-management;login-with-invalid-username-and-password" tests="3" failures="0" skipped="0">
        <properties>
            <property name="@login" value="true">
            </property>
            <property name="URI" value="C:\dev\cucumber-e2e-test\test\e2e\features\login.feature">
            </property>
        </properties>
        <testcase name="Given I am on the Portia home page" classname="authentication-management;login-with-invalid-username-and-password" time="3.8266756">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="When I login with &quot;Resman Priority&quot; account username &quot;invalidUsername&quot; password &quot;invalidPassword&quot;" classname="authentication-management;login-with-invalid-username-and-password" time="0.135447099">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="Then I should see a bad login error &quot;Error:&quot;" classname="authentication-management;login-with-invalid-username-and-password" time="0.0003946">
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="authentication-management;login-with-resman-priority-account-and-check-admin-preferences-menu" tests="5" failures="0" skipped="0">
        <properties>
            <property name="@login" value="true">
            </property>
            <property name="URI" value="C:\dev\cucumber-e2e-test\test\e2e\features\login.feature">
            </property>
        </properties>
        <testcase name="Given I am on the Portia home page" classname="authentication-management;login-with-resman-priority-account-and-check-admin-preferences-menu" time="3.1795375">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="When I login with &quot;Resman Priority&quot; account username &quot;usernameResman&quot; password &quot;passwordResman&quot;" classname="authentication-management;login-with-resman-priority-account-and-check-admin-preferences-menu" time="0.146646599">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="Then I should login" classname="authentication-management;login-with-resman-priority-account-and-check-admin-preferences-menu" time="0.6696968">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="And I should see my username" classname="authentication-management;login-with-resman-priority-account-and-check-admin-preferences-menu" time="0.0635387">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="And I should not see Admin Preference menu" classname="authentication-management;login-with-resman-priority-account-and-check-admin-preferences-menu" time="0.018977601">
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
        <properties>
            <property name="@login" value="true">
            </property>
            <property name="URI" value="C:\dev\cucumber-e2e-test\test\e2e\features\login.feature">
            </property>
        </properties>
        <testcase name="Given I am on the Portia home page" classname="authentication-management;after-your-login,-you&apos;ll-be-redirected-url" time="3.1641503">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="When I login with &quot;Resman Priority&quot; account username &quot;usernameResman&quot; password &quot;passwordResman&quot;" classname="authentication-management;after-your-login,-you&apos;ll-be-redirected-url" time="0.143332">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="Then I should login" classname="authentication-management;after-your-login,-you&apos;ll-be-redirected-url" time="0.6617511">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="And I should redirected to url" classname="authentication-management;after-your-login,-you&apos;ll-be-redirected-url" time="0.000532401">
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: Can you manually create test cases & test run on public.tenant.kiwitcms.org and post it here so we can see how you would like the results to look like. What you are asking for isn't supported ATM and I need a definitive example of how you imagine things will look in Kiwi TCMS.

Comment: ATM the junit.xml parser uses only the information from the `testcase` XML tag and only the classname & name attributes. The way cucumber scenarios are translated into separate steps doesn't play that well with Kiwi TCMS.

Comment: One option is to parse the Cucumber output shown at the top where "Scenario:" will be the test case summary and the rest will be the actual steps to execute. Status (pass/fail) will be an aggregate of all statuses for that same scenario.   Later when/if Kiwi TCMS gains support for test case steps & step statuses we can adjust the parser.

Comment: The testsuite name & properties from junit.xml may be extended into tags (will not be very hard) but the rest doesn't seem feasible in your situation. Please comment on the various options.

Comment: https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org/runs/1424/ run and test cases are created. 
Is it possible to these?
1- Maybe I add testcaseid and testrunid in "Scenario" which is in cucumber feature steps AND communicate with Kiwi then if these scenarios are failed or passed
Related testcaseid which is in testrun, will be automatically passed or failed.
2- I add testcaseid and testrunid in xml results AND communicate with Kiwi then if these scenarios are failed or passed
Related testcaseid which is in testrun, will be automatically passed or failed.
3- Or other your suggestion

Comment: @AlexanderTodorov

Comment: I've examined the TR you linked above and found a few things: 1) TC summary is the Cucumber Scenario: line without the "Scenario:" prefix. 2) TC text doesn't match anything in your Cucumber output.    The existing automation parsers search by TC.summary so if these cases do not exist they will be created (with the text in given-when-then format). If they exist (e.g. created by hand) then they will be reused regardless of what the text is!  However we need to create a separate parser for cucumber output. I will open an issue about it.

Comment: Ozcan, can you also post not your Cucumber scenarios but the test output you get from your nodejs test runner ? Also if you can comment on the GH issue above with these details it would help others who are willing to work on this issue.

Comment: @AlexanderTodorov I add details in GH issue.Thank you